# Changetype INSERT_ROW executes on row move

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a Google Sheets App script which modifies a cell in the new row when a new row is added.  It works fine, but the function also runs unexpectedly when a row is moved (by dragging it up or down the sheet).  It looks like the 'INSERT_ROW' is being referenced even if a row is just moved.  I would like the function to only execute if a new row is explicitly added (insert row above/insert row below).  Is this possible?  Here's what I have so far.

```
function myAddRow(e) {
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if(e.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW') {
 var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
 sh.getRange(row, 18).setValue('=HYPERLINK("http://maps.google.com/maps?q="&S' + row + ',"Map")');
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Upon checking both insert row and move row have the same event object `e` content. Hence you cannot distinguish them by each other. You might just want to consider checking if a specific column in the row has empty value to determine which was a newly added row or a moved row

Comment: @RonM Consider adding a answer.

Comment: Actually, my earlier suggestion might still not work since upon doing further testing. When you move a row upwards, the active range row will match your destination row. But when you move a row downwards, the active range selected is the next row after your destination row (example you move row 3 to row 6, the active range will be in row 7). So it will still be difficult to determine when to execute your code.

Comment: You may consider using [`getMaxRows()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows) to get the number of rows and store the 'rows before' with [`PropertiesService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to make comparison.